# How to add rounded corners to a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, rounded-corners

It was my understanding that tables can have webkit border radius styles as other elements do:

HTML

```
<table class="list-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>tables are misunderstood</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.list-table {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 4px solid red;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

... so where am I going wrong? See here for a live demo: http://bootply.com/79469#

Comment: Has to do with table display. Set `.list-table` to `display: block;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `border-collapse: collapse;` rule.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kcFnS/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 4px solid red;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzweT/)

Answer (score 0):

Put your table in a div and do your border radius on the div and not the table

http://bootply.com/79471

```
    div {
    border: 4px solid red;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    }
```